# How we can get two rows before and  after for a given id in a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 10 rows

```
id  values
 1    a
 2    b
 3    c
 4    d
 5    e
 6    f
 7    g
 8    h
 9    i
 10   j
```

I want to get two rows before and two rows after for @id = 5.

How can get?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** This should work as expected (hopefully):

```
select id, value
from [table]
where id-@id >= -2 
AND   id-@id <=  2 
AND   id-@id <>  0
```

Here's the running sql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca4e5/3/0

Comment: @Indra - what do you mean "id number not in order" - how *else* are you defining which rows are "before" or "after" any given row - tables have *no* inherent order.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
select *
from table
where id in (3, 4, 6, 7)
```

If you are using a int variable @id, you can do it like this:

```
select *
from table
where id in (@id-2, @id-1, @id+1, @id+2)
```

---

To select the previous two:

```
select top 2 *
from tablename
where id < @id
order by id desc
```

To select the next two:

```
select top 2 *
from tablename
where id > @id
order by id asc
```

Comment: If we don't have serial values in the table? (i mean some can delete the rows) how we can get?